# Select2: How to add option dynamically when list is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 and have noticed that if there are not an `option` provided in the HTML (ignoring the blank one shown below to allow the placeholder to work), it won't let me dynamically add my own option.  Typically, when there are other options it creates a tag and inserts it into the list of results.

I have `templateResult` and `templateSelection` to allow the display of the dropdown options with images on the left of their option text.

jQuery:

```
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: "Select or enter a {{ $itemType->itemTypeName }}",
    createTag: function (params) {
        return {
            id: params.term,
            text: params.term,
            newOption: true
        }
    },
    templateResult: function (option) {
        if(!option.id)
            return option.text;

        if(option.newOption) {
            $result.text(option.text);
            $result.append(" <em>(NEW)</em>");
        }
        else {
            var optimage = $(option.element).data('image'); 
            var $optItem = '<span>';
            if(optimage)
                $optItem += '<div style="display:inline-block; width:40px; text-align:center; margin-right:10px;"><img src="' + optimage + '" style="max-height:40px; max-width:40px; margin:0; vertical-align:middle;" /></div>';
            $optItem += $(option.element).text() + '</span>';

            $result = $($optItem);
        }
        return $result;
    },
    templateSelection: function (option) {
        if(!option.id) {
            return option.text;
        }
        var image = $(option.element).data('image');
        if(!image){
            return option.text;
        }
        else { 
            var $item = '<span>';
            $item += '<div style="display:inline-block; width:40px; text-align:center; margin-right:10px;"><img src="' + image + '" height="40px" style="margin:0; vertical-align:middle;" /></div>';
            $item += $(option.element).text() + '</span>';
            return $($item);
        }
    },
    tags: true,
    selectOnBlur: true,
    multiple: false
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="itemID" name="itemID" required>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

If there are options that contain data inside the `<select>`, the jquery code creates a new tag, the `templateResult` function adds it to the list with "*(NEW)*" after it, and the user can select this newly created option as if it was there all along.

When there are no options with data in them, the `templateResult` function tries to execute `$result.text(option.text);` but it fails because there isn't a `$result` in existence yet.

How can I create `$result` when I try to add a new option?